# Parsing of JSON data in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am bit new to JSON.  The JSON file once retrieved from the server, looks like below.

```
{ success: true,
  message: null,
  result: 
   { employee1: 
      { name: 'Herry B',
        abbr: 'Hb',
        age: 43,
        salary: 13473.50,
        address: 'xxxdrer43erered drdre' },
     employee2: 
      { name: 'Sam R',
        abbr: 'Sr',
        age: 41,
        salary: 2561.52,
        address: 'fdre43n43 43h43 fd' },
     employee3: 
      { name: 'Rita H',
        abbr: 'Rh',
        age: 37,
        salary: 36923.43,
        address: 'dsfaz34n3  343z4 3' },
     employee4: 
      { name: 'Suman B',
        abbr: 'Sb',
        age: 25,
        salary: 1942.45,
        address: 'dfasru34 343r ' }
  } 
}
```

I have a ajax which looks like below:

```
function() {
      var jsonData = $('#json-data');

      var employeeData = "https://amstar.eu/employee_data";
      $.getJSON( employeeData, {
          format: "json"
        })
        .done(function( data ) {

          jsonData.empty();

          var output = "<div><table border=\"1\"> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Abbr</th> <th>Age</th> <th>Salary</th> <th>Address</th> <tr></tr>"

          for( row in data.result )
          {
            ........

            output += '<tr></tr>';
          }
          output += '</tr> </table> </div>';

          jsonData.innerHTML(output);  
          });
    })
```

The "........" part is where the problem is.  I cannot move forward on how to process the data. The **row** gives me "employee1", "employee2", ... but dont know how to get the details of each employee and print.

Can someone help here?

Comment: Try row.name or row['name']

Comment: That is not valid JSON.

Comment: @Quentin it is valid.  If I parse it using jade, it prints fine. I wanted to do it via javascript/ajax so that I can auto-refresh on demand.

Comment: @BTRNaidu — The code you provided in the question is absolutely not valid. Either jade has a very lax parser that is doing a lot of error recovery or what you provided is not a realistic example of the code you actually have.

Comment: @AyyoubDahhane I tried that but does not work.

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ say it's not valid. Shouldn't use single quotes round strings, and property names should be quoted.

Comment: It's not JSON. jQuery parses whatever the JSON is automatically to give you that _JS object_.

Comment: But yeah if your parser is ok with it, then you just need to access the property of the employee (same as you accessed the "result" property of "data") - `row.name` etc.

Answer (score 2):

[ES6 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) can simplify things here. No need for nested loops!

1) [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the JS object that jQuery parsed for you and return the rows you need to fill your table.

```
const rows = Object.keys(result).map(e => {
  return `<tr><td>${result[e].name}</td><td>${result[e].abbr}</td><td>${result[e].age}</td><td>${result[e].salary}</td><td>${result[e].address}</td></tr>`;
});
```

2) Add the rows to the table.

```
const table = `<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Abbr</th><th>Age</th<th>Salary</th><th>Address</th><tr></tr>${rows}</table>`;
```

3) Add the HTML to the page.

```
jsonData.innerHTML = table;
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kmh4d0n3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the properties of the JSON object and write those to the HTML.

E.g. employee1.name.

Try something like...

```
"<TD>" + row.name + "</TD><TD>" + row.abbr" + </TD>
```

There are nicer solutions to concatenating strings, but this should still work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pretty easily by using nested `for loops` along with `insertRow` and `insertCell` methods: no need for jQuery.

1. You have nested objects so you need to nest `for loops` to get the persons details.
2. You can then use your for loops to generate the tables rows.

   ```
   for (var row in data.result) {
       //insert new row for each employee
       var table_row = table.insertRow(-1);
       console.log('row:', row);
       for (var details in data.result[row]) {
           //insert new cell for every employee detail
           var table_cell = table_row.insertCell(-1);
           table_cell.innerText = data.result[row][details];
       }
   }
   ```